# Anomaly in mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

[image]

This was originally 1 cylinders edited into 1 object. For some reason, where I combined the 2 I have an extra edge that isn't showing in wire frame view. I tried merging by distance but that didn't do anything that I saw. How do I correct this.

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 2):

You have inverted normals, go in *Edit* mode, select all and press *Shift N* to recalculate the normals.